# Java Concurrency In Practice (2006) Figure 12.1 TimedPutTakeTest

Tags: java, graph, concurrency

In Figure 12.1 on page 263, I noticed the graph starts with 1.

Then I read the following on page 268:

"Therefore, tests of multithreaded performance should normally be mixed with tests of single-threaded performance, even if you want to measure only single-threaded performance. **(This issue does not arise in TimedPutTakeTest because even the smallest test case uses two threads.)**"

If the smallest test case uses 2 threads, where does the data for 1 thread in Figure 12.1 come from?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do people need to own the book edition you are talking about to answer your question?

Comment: I couldn't find the edition in the book, but I added the year to the title. I think it was the latest edition at the time when I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label *Number of threads* on Figure 12.1 is misleading.

It is in fact number of thread pairs:

```
...
for (int pairs = 1; pairs <= 128; pairs *= 2) {
...
```

Each TimedPutTakeTest uses 2 threads (single Producer and single Consumer) even for value 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nPairs; i++) {
    pool.execute(new PutTakeTest.Producer());
    pool.execute(new PutTakeTest.Consumer());
}
```

**Note:** The code in question is [available online](http://jcip.net/listings/TimedPutTakeTest.java).